# Combine two BETWEEN Rails queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

At the moment I'm doing my query like this:

`results = Points.where(latitude: (lat_low..lat_high))`

`result = results.where(longitude: (long_low..long_high)).first()`

It works but I can't help but think there should be a better way to pull out that one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Points.where({ latitude: (lat_low..lat_high), longitude: (long_low..long_high) }).first
```

Comment: I like this solution best - I prefer to use `.first` rather than `.limit(1)` and is why I accepted this answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

```
result = Points.where(latitude: (lat_low..lat_high)).
                where(longitude: (long_low..long_high)).
                first
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
result = Points.where( latitude: (lat_low..lat_high), longitude: (long_low..long_high)).limit(1)
```